# Is there a way that i can loop this program to start all over again after it executes part of a loop

Tags: java

Ok, I am new to Java and I'm encountering a problem. I'm trying to make the program start all over again from the main when a certain section of the switch statement has finished executing. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ans;
    System.out.println("Choose an option");
    System.out.print("1: To see members\n2: To add member\n3: To delete a member\n Option: ");
    ans = input.nextInt();

    switch(ans){
        case 1:
        //code to see members
        break;
        case 2:
        //code to add members
        break;
        case 3:
        //code to delete members
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid option");
        }
     }
 }
```

After case one finishes executing, the program exits. How do I pass control back to the main so that it can start allover again until the user exits on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one....

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
boolean run = true;
while(run){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ans;
    System.out.println("Choose an option");
    System.out.print("1: To see members\n2: To add member\n3: To delete a member\n4: To end the program\n Option: ");
    ans = input.nextInt();

    switch(ans){
        case 1:
        //code to see members
        break;
        case 2:
        //code to add members
        break;
        case 3:
        //code to delete members
        break;
        case 4:
        //it will end the program
        run=false;
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid option");
        }
       }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Extract the code from main into a new function, and then call that function to pass control and start over again.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean exitLoop = false;
while (!exitLoop) { 
    // insert code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a variable :

```
boolean run = true;
```

Put your code in a loop:

```
while(run){
    //your code
}
```

If the user chooses to quit just set run to `false` and the program will exit.

Comment: Please don't use duplicate answer given by MadProgrammer

Comment: sorry, but when i started to write there was only the first answer present.

Answer (score 0):

You could call recursively main (not recommended), or better, follow the answer given by @ipavlic and put it in a loop as said by others like @Dahaka.